# @media screen and (min-device-width: 1366px) and above not being recognized

Tags: html, css

for some reason, `@media screen only and (min-device-width: 1366px)` and above (`@media screen only and (min-device-width: 1600px)` etc) are not being recognzed.

I have a div `#contentSpace` which contains another div `#content`. `#contentSpace` should resize depending on the resolution / screen size.

HTML includes `<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />`.

I have tried `min-device.width`, `min-width`, removed and included `only` next to the screen. It does not help.

For example, this CSS works:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 100px) and (max-device-width: 719px) {
    #contentSpace{
        width: 90%;
        top: unset;
        right: unset;
        margin-top: 5vh;
        margin-left: 5vw;
    }

    #content{
        width: 90%;
    }
}
```

while this does not work...

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 1366px){
    #contentSpace{
        width: 70%;
        right: 15%;
    }
}
```

Any help/advice/suggestions are welcome.

Thank you

Comment: may be your screen size is less than 1366px?

Comment: No. I'm resizing by using Dev Tools (F12), so the resolution goes above 2K

Comment: Has been a long time since I have done css and using media screens. I can't remember all. But I have noticed that on the bottom you did not include "**only**".

Comment: check with just `min-width` instead of `min-device-width`

Comment: Just ran your code an everything works fine, you probably have some code elsewhere interfering

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have already included this in the question. I have tried `min-device.width`, `min-width`, removed and included `only` next to the screen. It does not help.

Comment: It works fine - https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/gbcvwx3o/12/

Comment: Thank you @LuísP.A. , but it still does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an hour of bashing my head against the wall, I discovered I forgot to close one of the `@media`s with }.